# Discord JS V12 issue checking if user already has role

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have a command where my bot is supposed to give a person that I mention in my message a role, the bot gives the user the role just fine. However when I run the command on someone who already has the role it doesn't stop and say "user already has role", it continues and says it `added the role to the user`.

Here's my code:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'pm',
    description: 'sets pm',
    permissions: ['ADMINISTRATOR'],
    execute(client, message, args, Discord){
        try {
            
            let role = message.guild.roles.cache.get("role id");
            let member = message.mentions.members.first();
            if(!member) return message.channel.send('***Error:*** Please specify a user.');
            
            if(member.roles.cache.has(role)) {
                message.channel.send(`***Error:*** ${member} is already a PM.`)
            } else {
                member.roles.add(role);
                message.channel.send(`Added ${member}`)
            }


        } catch (e) {
            message.channel.send(`***Error:*** ${e}`)
            console.log(e)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were really close. All you have to do is swap out `member.roles.cache.has(role)` with `member.roles.cache.has(role.id)`.

Reference: https://anidiots.guide/understanding/roles